# Install usb_modeswitch

Tags: usb, beaglebone-black

I'm working on a project which we use a Beaglebone Black that runs on Android. We need to use USB storages for data transfer. When I plug in a USB storage to Beaglebone it works well. But if I remove it (without going to settings and clicking unmount USB device) 'unsafely' and re-plug it, Android doesn't mount USB storage. It creates its folder in /dev/block/sd* but doesn't mount it to /storage/usb1 . So I tried to use dmesg command to findout what the problem is. And I think I find the source of the problem. dmesg says:

```
init: no such service 'usb_modeswitch'
```

I think my Android distribution doesn't have usb_modeswitch binary and because of that it can't re-mount USB storage. I searched the web and find [this site](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#download) . But I'm not a Linux guy and I was unable to create a binary for my Android. I think if I can create a binary and copy it to /system/xbin/ folder in my Beaglebone, It might work. But of course I might be terribly wrong :D If you can give me step - by - step instructions to create a usb_modeswitch binary, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Your problem is rather the "unsafe removal", which leaves the mount target "busy" (and besides is dangerous for your data, as it might result in data loss). Better than always have bullets removed is to not get shot in the first place, so remember to always *safely* remove. If it happens once, a reboot should fix it as well (learning the hard way yields good results I've learned, sarcastic as that might sound).

Comment: Actually we are developing a specific device for a project. Beaglebone will only have one app (which we are developing). And users won't be allowed to close application or go to settings for safe removal :) So I'm stuck with automated mounting. I tried to do it in code, but no luck. By the way rebooting device fixing the problem naturally. But it isn't an option for us :) We can't force users to reboot the device everytime they want to us USB :) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then you're out of luck, I'm afraid. Either you permit safe unmounting, or they'll have to risk data loss and have to reboot for re-connection of the storage. Once shot, you need to remove the bullet, or live with it. So better not risk being shot, as said. The bullet-proof vest is called "safe removal" here.